# How to run a Python script online every N minutes?

Tags: python

To work a bit on my Python, I decided to try to code a simple script for my private use which monitors sites with offers and sends you an email whenever a new offer which you are interested in pops out. I guess I could handle the coding part (extracting the newest one from HTML and such) but I've never really run online any script which requires being fired every N minutes or so. What kind of hosting/server do I need to make my script run independently of my computer and refresh every, say, 5 minutes sending me an email when there's an update?

Comment: You can use crontab to implement it if you online os is linux/unix.

Comment: I see, thank you. However, what I'm more interested in than the tool itself is what kind of thing do I have to store my script on? I mean - I guess the regular free hosting won't do as you don't have access to any shell there. Neither will Google Engine, rigth? So what should I run it on?

Comment: @Straightfw If you're asking for hosting recommendations, that's not really appropriate for SO. If you can only get web-based hosting for free, then you might be able to write a simple web application which spawns a daemon subprocess to run your script every so often.

Comment: As far as I know google app engine has cron capabilities and can send emails so it might work for you. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

Comment: @Aya - I'm not asking for hosting recommendation, I'm asking for the name of the type of hosting I need since I just don't even know what to google for :D

Comment: @Zuljin - oh, that's great! Will stick to GAE then, I think :) Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shell access, you an use [`crontab`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab) to schedule a recurring job.

Otherwise you can use a service like [SetCronJob](https://www.setcronjob.com/) or [EasyCron](http://www.easycron.com/) or similar to invoke a script regularly.

Some hosters also provide similar functionalities in their administration interface...